# How to notify parentview that an image in a childview has been loaded in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

How does a parentview get notified when an image in one of its childviews is fully loaded and present in the dom? I need to measure the complete height of all the children **after** all images are loaded. Since measuring it in `didInsertElement` is the incorrect height (it returns the height without the images height).

So this is how my view structure looks like:

```
{{#view App.ArtistBoxesView}}
  {{#each artist in controller}}
    {{#view App.ArtistBoxView}}
      <div class="artist">
        <div class="thumb">{{styledmediaitem artist.thumb style="thumb"}}</div>
      </div>
    {{/view}}
  {{/each}}
{{/view}}
```

Where `styledmediaitem` is a handlebars helper that outputs an `<img src=""/>` with the correct path to the server.

I'd like to get a notification in `ArtistBoxesView` when an image (or even better: when all images) in `ArtistBoxView` is/are fully preloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the [jQuery ImagesLoaded plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) from within your view's didInsertElement fx. Something like this should do the trick:

```
App.ArtistBoxView = Ember.View.extend({ 
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().imagesLoaded( function( $images, $proper, $broken ) {
      console.log( $images.length + ' images total have been loaded' );
      console.log( $proper.length + ' properly loaded images' );
      console.log( $broken.length + ' broken images' );
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to hook into an event like `didInsertElement` without defining a custom view? For example, if I just have a template with img src attributes bound to controller properties, how can I use imagesLoaded to observe them? I've tried just defining something like `$('.mycontainer').imagesLoaded(function() { /* foo */ }` but it doesn't seem to work.